# Statements true for all n Vs. statements true as n->infty

Tags: logic, induction, infinity

Let P be a statement.

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the following statement to be true?

(P is true $\forall n \in \Bbb N$)$\implies$(P is true as n$\to \infty$)

As background for this question, I understand $0 \in \bigcap_1^n(-1/n,1/n)$ $\forall n \in \Bbb N$. However, I am not entirely clear as to why $0 \in \bigcap_1^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$.

After all, $-1/n,1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but $(-1/n,1/n)$ does not contain both -1/n and 1/n, so why should $0 \in \bigcap_1^\infty (-1/n,1/n)$?

Also, if $c_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ with $c_n<1$ $\forall n \in \Bbb N$, then is it true that $\bigcup_1^\infty [-c_n,c_n]$ = $(-1,1)$?

Comment: The definition of the notation $\cap^{\infty}A_i$ is the things that are in $\cap^nA_i$ for all $n$.

Comment: The finite intersections are neither needed nor used in the proof that $0$ is in the intersection of all our intervals. All that is needed is that $0$ is in each interval.

Comment: My confusion is that infinity is not a natural number, but it seems we are treating it as one when we say the implication is true.

Comment: David, to the edit the answer is yes. Again, the definition should be sufficient to work this out. When is some element is in the union? Whenever it is in at least one of the intervals. Because $c_n\to 1$, every element in $(-1,1)$ is smaller than some $c_n$, but indeed $\pm1$ are not in any of these intervals, so they cannot be in their union.

Answer (score 2):

The implication from "$\forall n\in\Bbb N$" to "For sufficiently large $n\in\Bbb N$" is always true. Because if it's always true... then it's always true.

The reverse implication, of course, fails to hold.

As for the reason $0\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$, it's easier to think about when any element is in an intersection of any family of sets. When it's a member of all the sets in the family. $0$ has this property, $0\in\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$. Therefore it is in the intersection.

Don't think about unions or intersections are limits. This is the union of a family of sets. Is the family finite? Infinite? Uncountable? Nobody cares, because we have an excellent definition:

> Let $I$ be any non-empty index set, and let $A_i$ be a set, for every $i\in I$. We define the following: $$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i = \{x\mid\exists i\in I.x\in A_i\}\\\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i = \{x\mid\forall i\in I.x\in A_i\}$$

Now $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$ is simply the intersection where $I=\Bbb N$, and $A_i=\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$. It is not the limit of some sequence, and thinking about it as such *can* be confusing.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand the second part of what you said, but my confusion is in the fact that infinity is not a natural number, but it seems like we are treating it as one in the implication statement in my question.

Comment: David, no one is treating infinity as a natural number. Why would you think that? (So we may attempt to clarify your confusion)

Comment: I think my confusion emanates from the following. (P is true for all n) implies (P is true as n-> inf). However, (P is true for all n) iff (P is true for each and every n). So then (n=inf for some n). This must be false, but I don't see why. I think you are right when you say I am using the concept of a limit when I shouldn't be.

Comment: I still don't understand where does infinity as a natural number comes in. To write $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is only to say that for every $n$ which is greater or equal to $1$, we have $x\in A_n$. There is no $A_\infty$.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think I was confused when I thought "(as n approaches infinity) entails (including n when n = infinity)" which is not necessarily true. Thank you! I think I have the correct thoughts on it now.